# How to select a list element that is hidden or in a table

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I need some help understanding the logic behind selecting list elements when they are in a table and may be hidden. Earlier I had posted a similar question and was able to figure out how to get to the elements however this one eludes me.

The last try was this:
    @b.table(:class => "ContractPriceTable").select_list(:class => "ContractPriceSourceLocale").option(:text => "Japanese (Japan)").select

```
<table id="ContractPriceTable" class="table table-bordered table-nomargin ContractPriceTable">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="s2id_Contracts_142c5493-fc46-4608-91f9-addfcc04162d__ContractTranslationQualities_293ac7e9-f083-4c27-abeb-41b90e907716__ContractPrices_7fc81280-14c2-4a1b-a659-af99105af152__CurrencyId" class="select2-container select2 visible currency-select">
    <a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <input id="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text">
    </div>
    <select id="Contracts_142c5493-fc46-4608-91f9-addfcc04162d__ContractTranslationQualities_293ac7e9-f083-4c27-abeb-41b90e907716__ContractPrices_7fc81280-14c2-4a1b-a659-af99105af152__CurrencyId" class="select2 visible currency-select select2-offscreen" name="Contracts[142c5493-fc46-4608-91f9-addfcc04162d].ContractTranslationQualities[293ac7e9-f083-4c27-abeb-41b90e907716].ContractPrices[7fc81280-14c2-4a1b-a659-af99105af152].CurrencyId" data-val-required="The CurrencyId field is required." data-val="true" tabindex="-1">
    <option value="b32ad865-00b7-4969-b9af-053538405bf8">Yuan (CNY) - ¥</option>
    <option value="a6f8185b-4119-4b4b-8c23-7211bef8b2bd">Japanese (Japan)</option>
```

Comment: That is a pretty gnarly chunk of HTML. Any chance of stripping that down to a more minimalist example?

Comment: that is the minimalist example :) let me know if the formatting helped.

Comment: You have stripped the HTML too far as now the Watir code no longer matches - eg there is no table and there is no Japanese option. Please also clarify what happens when you tried your code - eg was there an exception.

Comment: The Watir code is looking for a select element with class "ContractPriceSourceLocale" but the HTML shows the class as "select2 visible currency-select select2-offscreen". That would explain why the element cannot be found.

Comment: As Justin Ko points out, that select element isn't in the HTML you provided. Is the HTML you provided perhaps mistaken, or should you modify your code?